# UISearchBar в iOS 11.1 и iOS 11.3

Tags: ios, swift

Вот мой код добавления этого бара

```
    var searchBar = UISearchBar()
    searchBar.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44).isActive = true
    navigationItem.titleView = searchBar
```

> searchBar.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44).isActive = true для того чтоб бар не расширял navigationBar

На iOS 11.1 он выглядит вот так [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
На iOS 11.3 выглядит нормально [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

***Вопрос в том как привести в норму на iOS 11.1***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема с кнопкой назад, т.к. она не подгоняет ширину сама.
Нужно найти эту кнопку и установить ей ширину:

```
func searchAndFixBackButton(in view: UIView) {
    if ["_UIBackButtonContainerView", "_UIButtonBarButton"].contains(String(describing: type(of: view))) {
        view.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44).isActive = true
    }
    for subview in view.subviews {
        searchAndFixBackButton(in: subview)
    }
}

// MARK: - применять в viewDidAppear:
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    searchAndFixBackButton(in: navigationController!.view)
    searchBar.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44).isActive = true
    navigationItem.titleView = searchBar
}

//либо добавляете в viewDidLoad Ваш searchBar и правите размер:
override func updateViewConstraints() {
    searchAndFixBackButton(in: navigationController!.view)
    super.updateViewConstraints()
}

//либо добавляете в viewDidLoad и в viewDidLayoutSubviews:
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    searchAndFixBackButton(in: navigationController!.view)
    searchBar.sizeToFit()
}

//Также можете добавить проверку на версию, если эта проблема только в 11.1:
if UIDevice.current.systemVersion == "11.1" {
    //Фиксим
}
```

Comment: Ответ правильный, но так как делается во viewDidApear сначала пустой NavigationBar, а потом ХОБА залетает поисковая строка

Comment: @Daniyal1909 обновил ответ.